# Why jQuery.animate is synchronous?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does this code work synchronously?

```
$this.animate( { 'left': '+=200px' } );
$this.animate( { 'top' : '+=200px' } );
```

I really doubt that it is possible to execute a function synchronously in JavaScript.

And

```
doSomething();
doSomethingMore();

function doSomething() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert('doSomething finished');
    }, 3000);
}

function doSomethingMore() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert('doSomethingMore finished');
    }, 1000);
}
```

How to not execute function doSomethingMore until function doSomething finished.
Or Something like that.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please explain your question. I can't quite follow.

Comment: @putvande is it easier to understand now that i cleaned up the grammar?

Comment: It's not synchronous, as the code executes & returns before the animation does actually take place. It just queues the animations, though.

Comment: "I really doubt that it is possible to execute a function synchronously in JavaScript. If possible, how?"  `function(a,b) { return a+b }` That executes synchronously, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Sunil D.-Now I update my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm just going to take a guess here, because i can't follow the jQuery source code either. :)

`.animate()` adds animations to a queue. By default this is `$.fx`. When an item is added to the queue: if it is the first, it is run; if it is not, it waits until it is the first item in the queue. Once jQuery has finished running the animation, it removes the first item from the queue (i.e. the animation that just finished), and runs what had been the second.
Therefore, it only *seems* to run synchronously. If you put another statement after the second call to `.animate()`, you'll see that it is actually executed immediately. This is also why `.animate()` takes a callback.

There are also other functions that let you manipulate the queue. For example `.stop()` and `.queue()`.

Comment: How jQuery know before animation finishes?-Thank you.

Comment: @user2438933 Sorry, i didn't understand your comment. Do you mean, how does jQuery know when the animation finishes?

Comment: You say "Once an animation finishes, the next one will start." How to?-Sory in my english TT

Comment: Yes, I got a queue concept now. If I want to implement my queue, how I know the fist has finished and set the second to wait, Sorry if my question not clear

Comment: @user2438933 jQuery takes care of running the animations in the proper order on its own. Is that what you were asking about?

Comment: If i've answered your question here, would you consider accepting the answer?

Comment: Um, i'm asking you in details about "jQuery queue". How they know the last order (the order before this order) finished.

Answer (score -1):

You are calling the method twice so it will do it the way it is currently working for it to work the way you want it to work you have to do in one call:

```
$this.animate({left: '+=200px',top : '+=200px'});
```

Comment: Not what the OP is looking for --  they want to know **why** it runs synchronously.